# iOS: Disable all touches for some time after calling 'prepareForSegue:'

Tags: ios, touch, transition, uistoryboardsegue

The problem is that user can tap two buttons that perform `push` segues in one moment, and in this case two view controllers are pushed one after another. Here is a code piece:

```
- (void)cellTapped:(MyCell *)cell
{
    NSLog(@"cell tapped %p", cell);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:cell];
}
...
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", [segue identifier]);
}
```

Console log when I tap immediately two buttons:

```
2014-05-22 18:33:09:622 zzz[1737:1547] cell tapped 0x17558e10
2014-05-22 18:33:09:631 zzz[1737:1547] prepareForSegue: MySegue
2014-05-22 18:33:09:873 zzz[1737:1547] cell tapped 0x17554720
2014-05-22 18:33:09:875 zzz[1737:1547] prepareForSegue: MySegue
```

So looks like it's a bug. I would like to disable touches on screen while segue is performing transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIApplication` offers you `beginIgnoringInteractionEvents` and `endIgnoringInteractionEvents` so you can disable all touch event handling during certain times (like a view transition).

Be sure to call `endIgnoringInteractionEvents` once for each time you call `beginIgnoringInteractionEvents`.

Comment: It's good point to control all touches. I must note that it doesn't solve my problem (if I call `beginIgnoringInteractionEvents` in `prepareForSegue:`). Looks like touches are processed with deferred mechanism. So I solved it with custom time-based flag in `cellTapped:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` or the superView of your tableView. This would cancel all touches that occur in any of your superView's subviews.

Comment: I have a complex UI and this code would be not easy to insert.